# Script to create file that is writeable by all machines on a domain

Tags: powershell, file-permissions

Still new to powershell but I've been tasked with figuring out how to create and run a powershell script on every workstation on our domain so that it pulls Bitlocker status and then writes info to a csv file. We use labtech as a our remote system so we want to run the script on each machine as our engineer doesn't want anything run on the DC itself (was originally going to pull all workstation names from the OU and then check status on each one). The problem is it seems the first machine to run the script creates the file and then takes ownership effectively locking all other machines out of writing to the file. Any suggestions to steer me in the right direction are appreciated. Thanks.

```
$Computer = hostname
Write-Host "Getting Bitlocker Status..." -ForegroundColor Green

function ErrorLog {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $Date = Get-Date
    $Date ERROR: "$ErrorMessage" | out-file *path* -Append 
exit
}
try
{
$Status = manage-bde C: -cn $Computer -status | Select-String "Conversion Status:", "Percentage Encrypted:", "Protection Status:", "Lock Status:"
}
catch
{
    ErrorLog

}
finally
{
    $Date = Get-Date
    "$Date Successful BitLocker Check" | out-file *path* -Append
}

Write-Host "Sending info to CSV file..." -ForegroundColor Green

try{
    $ConvStatus = $Status.line | Select-String "Conversion Status:"
    $Percentage = $Status.line | Select-String "Percentage Encrypted:"
    $LockStatus = $Status.line | Select-String "Lock Status:"
    $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        ComputerName = $Computer
        ConversionStatus = $ConvStatus.ToString().trim("Conversion Status:")
        PercentageEncrypted = $Percentage.ToString().trim("Percentage Encrypted:")
        LockStatus = $LockStatus.ToString().trim("Lock Status:")
}

    $Object | Select-Object ComputerName, ConversionStatus, PercentageEncrypted, LockStatus | Export-CSV *path* -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
}

catch {
    ErrorLog
}
finally
{
    $Date = Get-Date
    "$Date CSV written to $Path" | out-file *path* -Append

}
```

Comment: If you can't run the script on the DC, can't you run it on another machine? That will make it much easier to maintain. I.e there will only be one script only, and there won't be any issues with file permissions.

Comment: My original script pulled all workstation name from the Workstations OU and used a foreach loop to check the status on each machine and append a csv file. Unfortunately it seems only the DC has the bitlocker feature installed on it as the other servers don't recognize manage-bde. Our engineer does not want the bitlocker feature installed on other servers...even the UTIL server. Our other workstations are all on different subnets depending on their location so I'm unable to remote check status on all machines from my workstation. Seems I may be stuck

Answer (score 1):

Having all computers write to the same file concurrently is not a good solution.
It would be much preferable to query the Bitlocker status of all workstations
from one central computer of the domain.

The command to use is
[manage-bde](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/manage-bde), used for example as :

```
manage-bde -status -computername WS12345 C:
```

Which might give this output :

[image]

You may write a script that gathers the information into one CSV file.

References :

- [Checking Encryption Status of Remote Windows Computers](https://isjw.uk/checking-encryption-status-of-remote-windows-computers/)
- [Technet PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Query-BitLocker-status-on-f44e443c)
  to remotely query each computer found in the specified OU (using manage-bde.exe) to determine if BitLocker protection is on or off and report accordingly in colour-coded output.  The results will be saved to a CSV file and sent via email to the specified recipient(s). Just change the necessary variables as required and run.
- [Technet PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-get-BitLocker-193ef058)
  to get BitLocker Encryption Status for multiple computers.

Comment: +1 Strictly speaking this is not an answer to the question, but I think that it *does* explain what the OP needs to do. ( http://xyproblem.info/ )

Comment: That was my original plan however I need to run on a server as the workstations are all on different subnets so I can't run this remotely from my workstation. Our engineer is not allowing the bitlocker feature to be installed on the UTIL server and won't allow me to run a script on the DC. That's why I came up with this dirty way of trying to get a report

Comment: You could run the script once on each segment - it doesn't have to execute from the DC. Then merge the individual CSV files into one.

Comment: @Berend: Thanks for the nice link - one to remember.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make a call to icacls to grant Full Access to everyone:

```
icacls myfile.csv /grant everyone:F
```

Note that *everyone* is locale dependent, so if you're not using english, you should use another name.

Here's a link to an [article](https://www.business.com/articles/powershell-manage-file-system-acl/) that describes how to do this the Powershell way. It's a bit longer, and in this case I'd prefer the above oneliner myself. I modified the example from that page a bit:

```
$Path = 'myfile.csv'
$Acl = (Get-Item $Path).GetAccessControl('Access')
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule('Everyone', 'FullControl', 'Allow')
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl -path $Path -AclObject $Acl
```

BTW, have you considered what will happen if two pc's write to that file simultaneously?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to convince our engineer to make some changes and am now successfully running my original script via our UTIL server. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You answer would be more useful to future readers if you document whant changes your engineer made - otherwise it doesn't really help anybody.